# The admin route cannot be recognized with the existing token in React app

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express

**components/Route/AdminRoute.jsx**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { useAuth } from "../../context/auth"
import axios from "axios"
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom"
import Spinner from "../Spinner/Spinner"


export const AdminRoute = () => {
    const [ok, setOk] = useState(false)
    const [auth, setAuth] = useAuth()
    console.log(auth.token)

    useEffect(() => {
        const authCheck = async() => {
            const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:4000/api/auth/admin-auth")
            console.log(res)
            if(res.data.ok){
                setOk(true)
            } else{
                setOk(false)
            }
        }
        if(auth.token) authCheck()
    }, [auth.token])

    return ok ? <Outlet /> : <Spinner />
}
```

**routes/authRoute.js**

```
import { isAdmin, requireSignIn } from "../middlewares/authMiddleware.js"

router.get("/admin-auth", requireSignIn, isAdmin, (req,res) => {
    res.status(200).send({ ok: true })
})
```

**middlewares/authMiddleware.js**

```
export const requireSignIn = async(req,res,next) => {
    try{
        // console.log(req.headers.authorization)
        const decode = jwt.verify(req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1], process.env.JWT_SECRET)
        console.log(decode)
        req.user = decode
        next()
    } catch(error){
        console.log(error)
        res.status(500).send({
            success: false,
            message: "Invalid token",
            error
        })
    }
}

export const isAdmin = async(req,res,next) => {
    try{
        const user = await userModel.findById(req.user._id)
        console.log(user)
        if(user.role !== 1){
            res.status(401).send({
                success: false,
                message: "You are not authorized to access the resources",
            });
        } else{
            next()
        }
    } catch(error){
        console.log(error)
        res.status(401).send({
            success: false,
            error,
            message: "Error in middleware",
        });
    }
}
```

Error: JsonWebTokenError: jwt must be provided

In this full stack project, I am trying to access the admin routes by the user have been logged in and the token already exists. Even I used `jwt.verify` in `requireSignin` it still shows out the jwt error but when I test the route in Postman with the token it works fine. I could not figure out why in React app cannot recognize the jwt?